# Types of conversion of images

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

I am converting images to Base64 and sending them to websocket.

using javacript:

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg){
            return function(e){
                  aImg.src = e.target.result;
                   imageMessage = aImg.src;
            };
    }(image))
var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

In socket server I get the string:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,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......

So as much as the image size is bigger, the string will be longer.
And the socket is crashing.

My question is how to convert the image to small and simple string.

Comment: Try send binary data instead.

Comment: Is it possible with javasript ?

Comment: [FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer)